# Does an Internal Object in Java have a Reference?

Tags: java, memory, reference, jvm

If you had something like the following:

```
class MyClass {

    private class InnerClass {

    } 
}
```

In java. Does the inner class of the overhead of a 4 byte reference, or is it contiguous in memory with the parent class? To clarify, in addition does it have the 4 bytes of general object overhead information?

A "normal" java class has 8 bytes of overhead, a 4 byte reference plus 4 bytes of other information about the object, does an inner class also have 8 bytes of this?

Comment: It does have a reference *somewhere*, but I don't know where. Come think of it, isn't this the kind of thing decided by the JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner classes are like regular classes that get allocated on the heap when you create them and any memory allocation for that will happen at that time. An inner class will need to know its parent class.

**UPDATE** Based on your comment below - so technically inner classes are like normal classes as I mentioned above so you would incur memory usage when you create it/use it. Also if you have static members in your inner class it will add some memory usage since there will be a class object for the inner class.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Are you certain it _needs_ to know its parent class?

Comment: If it's not static, it may need to know its parent class (ie, if any member functions reference the parent class' members).

Comment: You can use MyClass.this from the inner class to reference the outer class so a reference must be stored somewhere.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - I am trying to find a link on the sun (oracle) website for an authoritative reference. I found this link http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Java-Comparisons.cfm - where it's mentioned - `if the inner class is static, then it can be instantiated without an outer class instance, otherwise, the inner class object must be attached to an instance of the outer class`. So we can imply that the inner class has to know who its parent is to stay attached. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: So I guess what I'm trying to figure out is, does an inner class have the same overhead as a main class? ie in a main class you have 8 bytes of overhead, a 4 byte reference plus identifying information, does an inner class have these 8 bytes as well?

Comment: @themaestro - addded some "meat" to the post to address your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just decompile InnerClass using [javap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html)

```
class MyClass$InnerClass extends java.lang.Object{
    final MyClass this$0;
    MyClass$InnerClass(MyClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example

```
class MyClass {
    private class InnerClass {
    } 
}
```

creating a MyClass object does not automatically creates an InnerClass object, so the object can't be "always inside the outer object". Even more, you can create any number of InnerClass objects for each MyClass object, so the MyClass object can't have enough space for all these objects.

```
//                                      numbers: MyClass  InnerClass
MyClass m = new MyClass();                 //        1         0
MyClass.InnerClass i = m.new InnerClass(); //        1         1
MyClass.InnerClass[] array =
   new MyClass.InnerClass[20];             //        1         1
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   array[i] = m.new InnerClass();
}                                          //        1        21
```

A MyClass object can be used wherever any other object can be used, so they need
all the normal information necessary for normal objects, too.

So, objects of the InnerClass have the same overhead as objects of normal classes, and even additionally one reference more (for non-static inner classes), since each inner object needs to know its outer object.